# regex to validate intl phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can anyone helps me to write a regex that satisfies these conditions to validate international phone number:

1. it must starts with +, 00 or 011.
2. the only allowed characters are [0-9],-,.,space,(,)
3. length is not important

so these tests should pass:

- +1 703 335 65123
- 001 (703) 332-6261
- +1703.338.6512

This is my attempt ^\+?(\d|\s|\(|\)|\.|\-)+$ but it's not working properly.

Comment: Why do this at all? Other cultures have different rules, e.g. `/` to separate area code and number. Seeing as you can't validate a phone number anyway, why not simply check it doesn't contain any alphabetic characters, or do no check at all?

Comment: I suppose it would help to clarify that `(,)` means either parenthesis and not an "escaped" comma. It confused me for a second.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up the regexp use square-brackets to define "OR" situations of characters, instead of `|`.

Below is a rewritten version of your regular-expression, matching the provided description.

```
/^(?:\+|00|011)[0-9 ().-]+$/
```

#### What is the use of `?:`?

When doing `?:` directly inside a parenthesis it's for telling the regular-expression engine that you'd want to group something, but not store away the information for later use.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Although it matches any "valid" phone number, it also matches some invalid phone numbers. The error is in the character class.

Comment: I used the same character escapes as in OPs example, that's why.

Comment: You should still use `\d` instead of the `0-9` for simplicity sake. Take a look at my answer. It's much more thorough.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I know my regular expressions, inside the character class I thought you were a nitpicker about having the `-` at another location than last. I than read OPs post and though "well, to simplify it I'll use a range - it's easier to read for beginners"

Comment: Look, there's no reason to get upset. I am simply trying to help. I saw an error in your regex and I pointed it out. Also, there's no need to try to make a regex more readable. Regular expressions are not supposed to be readable. If he/she has a question about how it works, he/she can ask away. Besides, he/she has used `\d` in the question so it's a given that he/she understands what it does. Google is also a resource. Props for explaining the non-capturing group.

Comment: I'm not upset, I'm the most annoying troll you will ever encounter on SO. And regular-expressions can be readable, and you should strive towards that, why make something who is already somewhat complicated even more complicated? Also; you should have put your comment on your own post since you aren't replying to anything in this one.

Comment: @TylerCrompton I never troll answers, I troll users like you (who must insist on bashing on others answers when their own is incorrect). Please check out my profile and go read the previously answered questions by me, you'll see that my posts are far from being trollified.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6105/discussion-between-refp-and-tyler-crompton)

Answer (score 0):

with only 1 space and more successive space is not allowed ( note the " ?" at the end of second group)

```
(\+|00|011)([\d-.()]+ ?)+$
```

**faster** (i guess) with adding passive groups modifier (?:) at the beginnings of each group

```
(?:\+|00|011)(?:[\d-.()]+ ?)+$
```

you can use some regex cheat sheets like [this one](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/) and [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)  for faster tuning this regex to your needs.

---

in case you are not familiar with Linqpad, you should just copy & paste this next block to it and change language to C# statements and press F5

```
string pattern = @"^(?:\+|00|011)(?:[\d-.()]+ ?)+$";

Regex.IsMatch("+1 703 335 65123", pattern).Dump();
Regex.IsMatch("001 (703) 332-6261",pattern).Dump();
Regex.IsMatch("+1703.338.6512",pattern).Dump();
```

Comment: You should use a character class. Take a look at my answer for an example. Also, the OP said that he/she wants a space allowed, not any whitespace.

Comment: thanks i correct 1 space constraint .but in which part i should use a character class

Comment: You can replace the `(\d|-|\.| {1}|\(|\))` with a character class such as `[\d. ()-]`

Comment: Also, although it doesn't affect the matching, you may want to use a non-capturing group as explained by @refp as the OP did not mention needing any capturing.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\+|00|011)[\d. ()-]*$
```

To specify a length (in case you do care about length later on), use the following:

```
^(?:\+|00|011)(?:[. ()-]*\d){11,12}[. ()-]*$
```

And you could obviously change the `11,12` to whatever you want. And just for fun, this also does the same exact thing as the one above:

```
^(?:\+|00|011)[. ()-]*(?:\d[. ()-]*){11,12}$
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be more valid than my answer? Your answer is misleading since the length of the number isn't necessary {A,B}, you are specifying the number of groups that should match, the phone number itself can be 1 000 000 characters with the above regexp.

Comment: There's three regular expressions above. Please specify which one. Like I stated, the second (and third) are for if he/she changes his/her mind about a possible length requirement. I just added it for fun. The first regex is exactly what he/she wants.

Comment: And I'm referring to the "length matching" of that specific group, as said; you are defining the number of group repetitions, not the overall "length".

Comment: Please stop being abrasive. Just because I corrected you on your answer gives you no right to be hostile to me. Anyway, when I use the term length, I am referring to the number of digits after the `(?:\+|00|011)`. He/she did not specify the maximum number of repeated non-digits so my answer is 100% valid. My regex meets all of the criteria given, so please do not say my answer is "invalid".

Comment: Pick your battles, I'm a troll that don't like people who think they got it all figured out when you are far from there (note that I'm not saying I'm there, so don't try to use that against me). I haven't been "hostile". **"rude"**, perhaps, but not "hostile". As said; I specified \s which will match whitespaces, an average user don't really see the difference between a space and a tab, forcing an user to use space is to me kind of imbecil, but that's just me. Saying that my regular-expression is invalid invalidates yours.

Comment: Well, this regex will still cach input such as `+2 098123 () 22-3`, I'm not sure empty parentheses are legal?

Comment: Without knowing the full criteria, it's difficult to come up with something perfect. Most people put no more than two non-numbers between digits (i.e. +0 (123).456.6789. So you could most certainly limit it with something like `^(?:\+|00|011)[. ()-]{0,2}(?:\d[. ()-]{0,2}){11,12}$`. The numbers are all still there. If the numbers were a valid phone number, one could put all the punctuation he/she wanted but he/she would still have all the numbers to make a phone call.

Comment: This regexp still gets spaces

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a completely different route (in fact I had the same problem as you at one point, except I did it in Java).

The plan here is to take the input, make replacements on it and check that the input is empty:

- first substitute `\s*` with nothing, globally;
- then substitute `\(\d+\)` by nothing, globally;
- then substitute `^(\+|00|011)\d+([-.]\d+)*$` by nothing.
- after these, if the result string is empty, you have a match, otherwise you don't.

Since I did it in Java, I found Google's libphonenumber since then and have dropped that. But it still works:

```
fge@erwin ~ $ perl -ne '
> s,\s*,,g;
> s,\(\d+\),,g;
> s,^(\+|00|011)\d+([-.]\d+)*$,,;
> printf("%smatch\n", $_ ? "no " : "");
> '
+1 703 335 65123
match
001 (703) 332-6261
match
+1703.338.6512
match
+33209283892
match
22989018293
no match
```

Note that a further test is required to see if the input string is at least of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ^(\([+]?\d{1,3}\)|([+0]?\d{1,3}))?( |-)?(\(\d{1,3}\)|\d{1,3})( |-)?\d{3}( |-)?\d{4}$
```

It is compatible with **E164** standard along with some combinations of brackets, space and hyphen.